# Spring SaajSoapMessageFactory - Exception in saving multipart

Tags: java, spring, multipart, saaj

I am creating an application to upload a file from browser. The web service client was build using the spring SaajSoapMessageFactory. Using websphere.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
  <property name="messageFactory">
    <bean class="com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

The spring web service throws the following exception during the file upload.

```
Exception created : [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageException: Could not write message to OutputStream: Error during saving a multipart message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:251)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:45)
```